# Can I use Promises to simplify cordova native calls

Tags: cordova, asynchronous, promise

I'm working on a Cordova mobile application. I want to interact with the native File API and I observe there are lot of callbacks coming in place.

Example code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file){
    readDataUrl(file);
    readAsText(file);
}

function readDataUrl(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as data URL");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function readAsText(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as text");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

function fail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}

</script>
```

Recently I heard about this framework called Promises. I visited their website and they talk about mostly managing the async AJAX calls. Can I use the Promises library with Cordova to simplify the async programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes of course you can use promises! I use them a lot in my angularjs / cordova applications. There we use the module `$q` which offers a good api.

As well I think you should probably look at the section of organising javascript code at http://superherojs.com/#organizing. They explain the use of modules and exports there which could help you to structure your code (right now the method `fail` for example would be a global available method which is not so nice from a perspective of reusability.

A possible function could look like this:

```
var FileReader = {
  // we use this to make sure that we only need the inited promises once.
  var initedPromise = null;
  function init(){
    if (initedPromise === null){
      initedPromise = $q.defer();
      // user $q.all([...]) here to resolve the promise when your requirements have been called:
      // - deviceready
      // - FSinited
      // - any other stuff you might want to do.
    } 
    return initedPromise.promise;
  }

  this.readAsText = function(file){
    var def = $q.defer();
    init().then(function(){
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        def.resolve(evt.target.result);
      };
      reader.onerror = function(evt){
        def.reject(evt);
      }
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }, function(e){
      def.reject(e);
    });
    return def.promise;
  }
};
```

You can now use this with:

```
FileReader.readAsText("file.txt").then(function(text){
  console.log(text);
},function(e){
  console.log("Failure on loading text file: "+JSON.stringify(e));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - check out ngcordova.com, as they have "promise-y" versions of many Cordova plugins.